# Unable to grant an EC2 instance access to an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have created an IAM Role and assigned `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policy to the role.

After that I have attached the IAM role to the EC2 instance as follows:

- Choose the Actions tab, choose Security, and then choose Modify IAM role.
- Select the IAM role that I just created, and then choose Save. The IAM role is assigned to the EC2 instance.

Now, when I login to the EC2 instance and I am still not able to connect to S3 and getting below error:

```
[root@ip-172-31-13-233 ~]# aws s3 ls

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
[root@ip-172-31-13-233 ~]#
```

Also `aws sts get-caller-identity` is generating below output.

```
[root@ip-172-31-13-233 ~]# aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "12345",
    "UserId": "CIDA6DCGK7EIXLKYUWLEN",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::12345:user/user1"
}
[root@ip-172-31-13-233 ~]#
```

Comment: Is it totally new instance? Maybe you have some per-existing credentials setup on the instance.

Comment: Does `aws sts get-caller-identity` output the correct role?

Comment: Your bucket doesn't have a bucket policy that would restrict its access?

Comment: Also check if your bucket doesn't have encryption enabled with KMS. Otherwise, you'd need to have KMS permission in your EC2 Role.

Comment: @AnthonyB. not for `ls`.

Comment: what kind of bucket policy do i need to set? It is a new instance and a new bucket

Comment: If you have any access blocking policy on the S3 bucket, deny always overrides permission. So, you may need to check S3.

Comment: @meallhour, as luk2302 mentioned, you need to run this `aws sts get-caller-identity` in order to know whether the correct role is being used. I mentioned about bucket policy but this is only when list object in bucket, not when listing buckets.

Comment: @Anthony B. I have run the `caller-identity` command and pasted the output in my question. does the output look okay?

Comment: ok, so aws cli is then using credential of user1 not the instance role. I guess you have installed aws cli and then run aws configure? On EC2 you don't need to do this. But now, what's happening is that user1 might not have access to S3

Comment: yeah that is correct. I have installed aws cli and then run aws configure. But now, I have deleted `.aws/credentials` file and also removed `S3readAccess` from `user1 IAM Policy.` After doing that I have created a role and then added that role to EC2 instance. So, now I should be able to run `aws s3 ls` as ec2 has access to s3.

Comment: remove the whole .aws folder and restart the instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other that might be helpful.
What's happening here is that the aws cli that has been installed has been configured with a user. When using EC2, there is no  need to do that. you can directly run aws cli and it would automatically fetch credentials from instance metadata (if a role is associated).
If, however you had created a user, then you have to go through those steps in order to revert everything back to default:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-user-role-credentials/

Comment: It is working now. Thanks a lot for your insights. Almost spent a day trying to figure it out.